# How can I get size in bytes of a column from result set in java jdbc?

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, resultset

```
ResultSet res

ResultSetMetaData rsmds= res.getMetaData();
int size = rsmds.getColumnDisplaySize(i);
```

gives the width of a column, I want to get size of a column in bytes. How can I do this?

Query for the result set:

```
SELECT * FROM LevelOne ORDER BY (SELECT NULL) OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 50000 ROWS ONLY;
```

create table query:

```
CREATE TABLE Q_680_6([Id] INT, [Title] NVARCHAR(MAX) DEFAULT '', [Description] VARCHAR(MAX) Dta_db.dbo.Q_680_6([Id] INT, [Title] NVARCHAR(MAX) DEFAULT '', [Description] VARCHAR(MAX) DEFAULT '', [StartDate] DATETIME DEFAULT NULL, [EndDate] DATETIME DEFAULT NULL, [Lead] NVARCHAR(MAX) DEFAULT '', [CreatedOn] DATETIME DEFAULT NULL, [CreatedBy] INT, [ModifiedOn] DATETIME DEFAULT NULL, [ModifiedBy] INT) END
```

Comment: please post your `CREATE TABLE` statement.

Comment: please find the question i have edited again @MikeNakis

Comment: please find the queries posted @MikeNakis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't derive this from the result set metadata. You can use [`DatabaseMetaData.getColumns(...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getColumns-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-), column `CHAR_OCTET_LENGTH`, but this is possibly not populated for data types other than `char`/`varchar`.

Comment: For the record, the current production release of Microsoft's JDBC Driver for SQL Server (v6.1) returns `2147483647` for the `CHAR_OCTET_LENGTH` of an `NVARCHAR(MAX)` column.

Answer (score 0):

`getColumnDisplaySize` is about the result set. It is not about the column specification.

You might find [this](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=6399) related discussion useful.